# ASP.NET MVC: How to call javascript function in Html.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When I edit single recored in page, I use checkbox to get a selected row not every row with an actionlink element, but it seemed I cant make this way happen through calling javascript code (function GetSelectedRow() should return an id). Could anyone have a nice idea?

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Index</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function GetSelectedRow() {
            var a = 0;
            var chkBoxes = document.getElementsByName("chkSelect");
            var count = chkBoxes.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                if (chkBoxes[i].checked == true)
                    a = chkBoxes[i].primaryKeyID;
            }
            return a;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <span style="width:20%">
        <%: Html.ActionLink("Add", "Create")%>
        </span>
        <span>
        <%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = GetSelectedRow()) %>
        </span>
        <span>
        <%: Html.ActionLink("Detial", "Details", new { id = GetSelectedRow() })%>
        </span>
        <span>
        <%: Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = GetSelectedRow()) %>
        </span>
    </div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>
                CategoryID
            </th>
            <th>
                CategoryName
            </th>
            <th>
                Description
            </th>
        </tr>
        <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
            <tr>
            <td>
             <%: Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.AppCategoryID })%>
            </td>
                <td>
                    <%: Html.CheckBox("chkSelect", false, new { primaryKeyID = item.AppCategoryID })%>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%: item.AppCategoryID %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%: item.AppCategoryName %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%: item.Description %>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <% } %>
    </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function RedirectUsingSelectedRow() {
    var id = GetSelectedRow();
    window.location = '../Controller/Details/' + id;
}
</script>

<a href="#" onclick = "RedirectUsingSelectedRow();">Edit</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mixing server and client that way won't work.  What you need to do, when a row is selected, is to manipulate the URL.  So rather than return a URL, have GetSelectedRow do:

```
function GetSelectedRow() {
  //existing logic minus return

  var link1 = document.getElementById("Link1");  //this would require giving links an ID
  link1.href = '<%= Url.Action("Detail", new { controller = "Details" }) %>' + 
     'id=' a.toString();
}
```

You have to change it from client-side javascript is the key, rather than doing that during the rendering process.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$('#GetSelectedRow').click(function() {  /* Your Code */  });
```

Calling java script function by id 'GetSelectedRow'. Instead of calling the function by id, you can directly call the function

```
<% Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Controller", new { onclick = "GetSelectedRow();"}) %>
```